# HTTPS causes redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

No matter what simple rule I put in to force SSL, a redirect loop happens. I've been looking up different ways to force SSL for days and I currently have

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

as the only rule in .htaccess, which shouldn't cause an infinite redirect loop, but even this causes a redirect loop.  Any idea what could be going on?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.test.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This rule does work, although not for subfolders.  Not sure what the difference is though. Could there be something going on in a config file in apache? If so, what would I be looking for?

edit - Checked ports as well (Apache 2.4) just in case. 80 is still http and 443 is still https.

Comment: Are you sure something else isn't redirecting? Like a CMS, javascript or something in your content?

Comment: There's no CMS or anything. Edited post to show something that did work, although not for subfolders.

Comment: Test this in Chrome dev tool and see what URLs you get in Net tab